# self-normalizing subgroups of the unitary groups

Tags: group-theory

I have an open question: what is known about self-normalizing subgroups of the unitary groups? By "self-normalizing subgroup," I mean a subgroup that is its own normalizer in the larger group. Has there been any (partial) classification?

Comment: "Unitary group"...over what field, say? And is it the special, projective special or just *unitary group*?

Comment: the subgroup U(n) of GL(n,C)

Comment: if the problem is easier for SU(n), this is also fine